# Al hacer un inject en module marca error

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Estoy manejando `Angularjs 1.7`, intento utilizar **datatables** o **grid** para mostrar mi información, pero al utilizarlos e incluirlos en mi `module`, me marca error

ejemplo:

```
var app = angular.module('odemApp', ['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngGrid']);
```

o

```
var app = angular.module('odemApp', ['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','datatables']);
```

Y me marca lo siguiente

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

De antemano gracias y alguien me pueda orientar.

Comment: Porqué en el `module` estas terminando con una coma la inyección de librerías?

Comment: Fue error de dedo al poner el codigo en la pregunta, originalmente no termino con coma. Saludos.

Comment: que pasa si quitas *angularUtils.directives.dirPagination*? te sigue lanzando el error?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera aún quitando, tanto : 'ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Estas seguro que el error te lo da en el module y no en algún controller, directive, service o factory?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, en teoría la ayuda tanto de datatable, como grid, indican que se agregen los archivos o los cdn's y en modules se haga referencia, es lo único que hago.

Comment: Es raro, además no puedo replicar el código porque busque esas librerías y no las encontré a excepcioón de `ngRoute`, si me facilitas los links o cdn, podemos hacer algo ;)

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Los links son: [ http://ui-grid.info/ ] y [ https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome ] ó alguna opción que me recomienden para mostrar mi información en una tabla ó grid.

Comment: Yo cuando trabajo con datos y tablas, uso [SmartTable](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), que es excesivamente fácil de implementar. Podrías probar, de todas maneras haré la prueba con los links que me enviaste

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera muchas gracias por tu ayuda, reviso la información que me indicas.

Comment: Creo que encontre un posible error con *datatables*, que version estas incluyendo en tu proyecto de esta libreria

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera estoy agregando según yo la que esta en el mismo link, según esto es: v0.6.x

Comment: Te dejo este [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pauloc1989/pen/RwWZLME) que me funcionó perfecto con *datatables*

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera gracias, reviso, posiblemente sea la estructura de mi proyecto y deja pruebo la recomendación de  SmartTable.